# Excel Formula based on previous rows

Tags: excel, formatting, rows

[image: Example]

There are 3 columns:

**Date**, **Name**, **Bonus_Point?**

If a player scores a 4 or lower in the **Name** Column for three consecutive **Dates**, then **Bonus_Point** will return a 'Yes' or 'No'

For example, for 1/30/22, there would be a 'Yes' because there were 3 previous instances (including 1/30/22) where the score is less than or equal to 4.

But for 2/2/22, **Bonus_Point?** would be 'No' because on the third day, **Name** scored a 5.

Comment: Does checking the three values (and ANDing the result of the comparisons) not work? What error are you getting?

Comment: I have not written a formula yet because I don't know how to sequentially check the last 3 previous rows and have it restart after its checked the last 3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your columns are A through C, and the row 1 is the header row and your data is in rows 2 and down, enter this formula in C4:

```
=AND(B2<=4,B3<=4,B4<=4)
```

Then fill down. (See further down for "yes" and "no")

| Date | Name | Bonus_Point? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/28/22 | 3 |  |
| 1/29/22 | 3 |  |
| 1/30/22 | 3 | TRUE |
| 1/31/22 | 3 | TRUE |
| 2/1/22 | 4 | TRUE |
| 2/2/22 | 5 | FALSE |
| 2/3/22 | 2 | FALSE |
| 2/4/22 | 5 | FALSE |
| 2/5/22 | 4 | FALSE |
| 2/6/22 | 3 | FALSE |
| 2/7/22 | 2 | TRUE |
| 2/8/22 | 3 | TRUE |
| 2/9/22 | 4 | TRUE |
| 2/10/22 | 3 | TRUE |
| 2/11/22 | 2 | TRUE |
| 2/12/22 | 2 | TRUE |
| 3/13/22 | 3 | TRUE |

If you want "Yes" and "No", you can do that through formatting or add it to the formula:

```
=IF(AND(B2<=4,B3<=4,B4<=4),"Yes","No")
```