# Excel formula to be conditional on sequence of 'guesses'

Tags: excel

[image]

The columns of interest are **bonus?** and **points_earned**.
For each day, players submit a number of guesses, and I'm trying to write a formula for the **bonus?** column such that **if a player has 3 or fewer guesses on 2 consecutive days**, then the bonus column returns **Yes.**

In the picture, I've provided an example. For John Doe, on 1/28/22, **bonus?** is "No" because it is the first day and the streak below 3 guesses is 1. But on 1/29/22, that streak is now 2, and **bonus?** is now "Yes". On 1/30/22, John Doe records a score <= 3 but **bonus?** returns "No" because **I want the streak to restart after a Yes has been recorded on the previous day.**

Similarly for Jane Doe, on 1/28/22 and 1/29/22, both are "No" because the streak was 1 on 1/28/22 but a guess of 4 was recorded on 1/29/22. On 1/30/22 and 1/31/22 however, we have a streak of 2 and **bonus?** returns "Yes".

Also, the points_earned column is going to map the 'guesses' to the score, which will be equal to **points_earned**. If a player received a bonus, then 2 extra points will be added to points_earned.

How can I write a robust formula for the bonus column?

Comment: Have you looked at countifs()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel Formula based on previous rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70898324/excel-formula-based-on-previous-rows)

Comment: How can I use countifs?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842